# "unable to auto-detect email address (got '@.(none)')" local server

Tags: git

I'm trying to use a Git server on a local network, i've maded one repository folder in a server, share it and i actualy could make all the git inputs from one machine but from another one i get the error:

> unable to auto-detect email address (got '@.(none)')

I've also looked for this error but i only found material regarding the Git Hub itself and not in cases of local server...
I also try the steps below with no success:

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: We use a local server and have never seen this. Each user issues the two `git config --global` commands you quote and that works fine for us. Can you show actual commands you run that cause this error, and some setup steps so we can try to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Hi joanis, i get this error when i try to commit, i can add normally, when i check for the status, i receive the message that i have Changes to be committed, when i try to commit with the command "git commit -m "test", i get the error... Do you have any ideia on what could possible cause this error?

Comment: And i could clone a project from the server, what i can't do is commit any changes at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just found my error here...
In the question i quote:

> git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
>   git config --global user.name "Your Name"

But i was actualy using:

> git config --global user.mail "you@example.com"

So i've changed to:

> git config --global user.email "you@example.com"

And works fine.

Thank you all for the time expend helping me.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. That was subtle. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
git config --global
```

That will impact a user account home folder: ~/.gitconfig

If your process is executed not as that user, but as (for instance) root, it would not use the same config.
Try those commands without `--global`, and in the cloned repo folder, to make that a local config to the repo: that would be read by any user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've tried those commands without the --global as you said but, i'm still getting the same result, honestly, i don't understand what is happening here...

Comment: @GabrielSassaki Did you test those command in the right folder? That is in the root folder of your Git repo?

Comment: I believe so, i test in the main repo folder in the server and also in the main local repo folder, also try in the project local folder, all with no success...